# How to really disable beforeunload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A lot of web pages try to make you don't exit them by using the beforeUnload event on JS. Facebook, for instance, will show a warning if you try to use back / forward button , as the image below shows :

[image]

To avoid this i always used the code below to 'unbind' the event :

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

But this is not working anymore. Even after running the code below, the warning message will still shows if i try to leave the page.

How to really get rid of these messages in a web application ? Facebook is only an example, i'm trying to do this using JS for study purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The event is probably being registered via `addEventListener` rather than `onbeforeunload`. You could try adding a new event listener that overrides the previous one.

```js
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}, true);
```

The third parameter being `true` causes the event to go all the way down, so any other listeners will  be prevented.

Comment: Thanks but still won't work, you can simulate it on Facebook ; even after running the code above in devtools, the page still won't let you go back or forward without the confirmation